# obj-c collectionView adding header

Tags: objective-c, header, uicollectionview

I try to add a header to each section of the collectionView.

The collectionView without header works fine. When I checkmark the `Accessories Section Header` in Interfacebilder, the header will be shown in the simulator.

I added a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` Class (as File) and called it within the `viewDidLoad` of my `UICollectionView` Controller. In the FlowLayout I want to configure the zIndex and Size.

Now the header will not be shown in the simulator, additionaly I added breakpoints in the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but they will never be hit...

**How do I get the headers shown in the collectionview, and how do I influence the `zIndex` and `size` of the header in the correct way?**

#### SurroundViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SurroundViewController : UICollectionViewController    
@end
```

#### SurroundViewController.m

```c
#import "SurroundViewController.h"
#import "MagazineCell.h"
#import "LazyJoeHeaderLayout.h"

static NSString * const cellID = @"cellID";

@interface SurroundViewController ()

@end

@implementation SurroundViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = [[LazyJoeHeaderLayout alloc] init]; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    return mCell;
}

#pragma mark Collection view Layout things
// Layout set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Settings Size for Item at index %d", indexPath.row);
    CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);
    return mElementSize;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edgees of whole screen - not mElementsize
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); 
}
@end
```

#### LazyJoeHeaderLayout.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LazyJoeHeaderLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
@end
```

#### LazyJoeHeaderLayout.m

```c
#import "LazyJoeHeaderLayout.h"

@implementation LazyJoeHeaderLayout

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:indexPath];

    attributes.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    attributes.zIndex = 1024;

    return attributes;
}
@end
```

MagazineCell.h and MagazineCell.m not listed as not needed for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to show the header, below the updated code to my question, regarding the headersize.

#### SurroundViewController

```c
#import "SurroundViewController.h"
#import "MagazineCell.h"
#import "LazyJoe.h"

static NSString * const cellID = @"cellID";

@interface SurroundViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) LazyJoe *lazyJoe;

@end

@implementation SurroundViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.lazyJoe = [[LazyJoe alloc]init];
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = self.lazyJoe; // Layout things are in the Flowlayout

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MagazineCell *mCell = (MagazineCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    mCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    return mCell;
}
```

#### LazyJoe.m

```c
#import "LazyJoe.h"

@implementation LazyJoe

- (id)init {
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;

    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(104, 104);
    self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0); // That the items can align as nearest as possible
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2.0f; // spacing between items in one row
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 2.0f; // spacing between lines
    self.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width, 140);

    return self;
}

@end
```